# How to count amount of rows before certain value in clickhouse

Tags: sql, clickhouse

I have a table in Clickhouse that consists of device_id, event_name and event_ts (timestamp) where event_name can be either 'purchase' or 'ad'. How can I count how many ads user watched before made a purchase?

I tried to do it with ROW_NUMBER and subqueries but don't understand how I can match them back together (subqueries with 'purchase' and 'ad')

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
SELECT 
  *
, sum (if (event_name = 'ad', 1, 0)) over (partition by device_id order by event_ts)
    as c
FROM VALUES 
(
  'device_id UInt32, event_name String, event_ts DateTime'
, (1, 'purchase', now())
, (1, 'ad'      , now() - interval 1 MINUTE)
, (1, 'ad'      , now() - interval 2 MINUTE)
, (1, 'purchase', now() - interval 3 MINUTE)
, (1, 'ad'      , now() - interval 4 MINUTE)

, (2, 'purchase', now())
, (2, 'ad'      , now() - interval 1 MINUTE)
)
)
WHERE event_name = 'purchase'
ORDER BY device_id, event_ts desc

|device_id|event_name|event_ts               |c  |
|---------|----------|-----------------------|---|
|1        |purchase  |2023-07-15 16:31:01.000|3  |
|1        |purchase  |2023-07-15 16:28:01.000|1  |
|2        |purchase  |2023-07-15 16:31:01.000|1  |
```